# Publish console application via command line using specific publish profile

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, publish

I try to build and publish my .NET Core applications on the command line using predefined publish profiles.

For a ASP.NET Core application this (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/web-publishing-vs#publish-profiles)) works:

```
dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ReleaseFolder
```

But for a console application (where the publish profile is called `FolderProfile`, the following does not work:

```
dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

It builds the project but does not publish it.

So how can I publish a console application using a predefined publish profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publish profile support is part of the web-SDK which is used by the web targets. ASP.NET Core applications typically use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` wheres console applications use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` project.

Since console applications therefor don't include the web SDK's publishing support, you can only use the `Publish` target which generates deployable outputs. It is wrapped by the dotnet cli's `dotnet publish` command and can alternatively be used as `msbuild /t:Publish`. This publish command has no support for publish profiles since it is only a filesystem based operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can now add the [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/tree/bff968439a96e33e91753f4ef637f22ab75ff616/src/Publish) sdk to your project file. That will enable you to use `dotnet publish` for your project.

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">`